# Derive distribution by using the distribution of its norm and isotropically distribution property

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, chi-squared

I got the problem with hints but I don't get the hints. Hope someone can shed light on my doubts.

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $n$-dimension isotropically distributed vector in complex space $\mathbb{C}^n$ with norm $\sqrt{\rho n}$.

$H$ is circularly complex Gaussian scalar random variable $\mathcal{CN}(\mu_H,\sigma_H^2)$.

$\mathbf{W}$ is circularly complex Gaussian vector $\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma_w^2 \mathbf{I}_n)$.

$$\mathbf{Y}=H\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{W}$$

Prove that the conditional PDF of $\mathbf{Y}$ given $H=h$ is
$$P_{\mathbf{Y}|H}(\mathbf{y}|h)= \frac{\Gamma(n)}{\pi^n\sigma_w^2(\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert |h| \sqrt{\rho n})^{n-1}} \exp\left(-\frac{\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2 + |h|^2\rho n}{\sigma^2_w}\right) I_{n-1}\left(\frac{2\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert |h| \sqrt{\rho n}}{\sigma_w^2}\right)$$

where $I_n(.)$ modified [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) with paramater $n$.

### Hint 1

Given $h$, the random variable $(2/\sigma_w^2)\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2$ follows a [noncentral $\chi$-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with $2n$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter $|h|^2\rho n \times 2/\sigma_w^2$.

***My doubt***

Note that $h$ is scalar and other random variables are vectors. We have
\begin{align}
||\mathbf{y}||^2 &= |h|^2 ||\mathbf{x}||^2 + \mathbf{x}^*h^*\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{w}^*h\mathbf{x} + ||\mathbf{w}||^2 \\
&=|h|^2 \rho n + \mathbf{x}^*h^*\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{w}^*h\mathbf{x} + ||\mathbf{w}||^2\\
2/\sigma_w^2||\mathbf{y}||^2 &=2/\sigma_w^2 |h|^2 \rho n + 2/\sigma_w^2 \left(\mathbf{x}^*h^*\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{w}^*h\mathbf{x} + ||\mathbf{w}||^2\right)
\end{align}

Of course $\big( |h|^2 ||\mathbf{x}||^2 + ||\mathbf{w}||^2 \big)$ follows $\chi$-squared distribution, but what about the part $\big( \mathbf{x}^*h^*\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{w}^*h\mathbf{x} \big)$ ?

### Hint 2

$\mathbf{y}$ is also isotropically distributed. We can derive $P_{\mathbf{Y}|H}(\mathbf{y}|h)$ by using the formula of $n$-dimensional complex sphere of radius $\sqrt{\rho n}$

$$S = \frac{2\pi^n (\sqrt{n \rho})^{2n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}$$

***My doubt***

Is it simply $P_{\mathbf{Y}|H}(\mathbf{y}|h) = \frac{1}{S} \times P_{\left\Vert\mathbf{Y}\right\Vert^2|H}(\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2|h)$ thanks to the "isotropically distribution" property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, the trick is to notice that for fixed $X$ we can split $W$ into $wX+W’$ where $w$ is normally distributed and $W’$ is a normally distributed vector orthogonal to $X$ ($2n-1$ degrees of freedom). You then get an expression for $\|\mathbf y\|^2$ as a sum of squares of normal variables one of which has nonzero mean.

For 2: yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. However, even if $W = wX+W'$ and $W'$ is orthogonal to $X$,

\begin{align}
||\mathbf{y}||^2 &= |h|^2 ||\mathbf{x}||^2 + \mathbf{x}^*h^*\mathbf{w} + \mathbf{w}^*h\mathbf{x} + ||\mathbf{w}||^2\\
&= |h|^2 ||\mathbf{x}||^2 + \mathbf{x}^*h^*(w\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{w'}) + (w\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{w'})^*h\mathbf{x} + ||\mathbf{w}||^2\\
&= |h|^2 ||\mathbf{x}||^2 + ||\mathbf{x}||^2 h^* w + ||\mathbf{x}||^2 h w^* + ||\mathbf{w}||^2 \\
&= |h|^2 n\rho + n\rho \times 2 \mathcal{Re}\{h^* w\} ||\mathbf{w}||^2
\end{align}

where $\mathcal{Re}$(.) is real part of a complex variable

Comment: $||\mathbf{w}||^2$ follows $\chi$-squared distribution while $\mathcal{Re}\{h^* w\}$ is a scalar real Gaussian random variable and we don't have "a sum of squares of normal variables".

Comment: @AlexTP: use real coordinates. Assume by symmetry that $HX=(|h|\sqrt{\rho n},0,\cdots,0).$ Then $\|y\|^2$ can be written as the sum of $y_1^2$ and $y_2^2+\dots+y_{2n}^2.$ These $y_i$’s are independent, and $y_1$ is $N(|h|\sqrt{\rho n},\sigma_w^2/2)$ distributed, while the other $y_i$’s are $N(0,\sigma_w^2/2)$ distributed.

Comment: It seems obvious to you but I don't get it that in your latest comment, you are deriving the distribution of $Y$ for a given $H = h$ and a given $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x}$. 
$$P_{\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{X},H}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x},h) = \mathcal{CN}(h\mathbf{x}, \mathbb{I})$$

and $P_{\left\Vert\mathbf{Y}\right\Vert^2|\mathbf{X},H}(\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2|\mathbf{x},h)$ is clearly $\chi$-squared distribution.

Comment: However what I want to ask is that how

$$P_{\left\Vert\mathbf{Y}\right\Vert^2|H}(\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2|h) = \mathbb{E}_\mathbf{X}\{P_{\left\Vert\mathbf{Y}\right\Vert^2|\mathbf{X},H}(\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2|\mathbf{x},h)\}$$

is also $\chi$-squared.

Comment: @AlexTP: for fixed $h,$ the distribution of $\|y\|$ is independent of $X.$ This is because of radial symmetry, or can be seen from the fact that the distribution of $\|y\|^2$ you get from conditioning on $X$ and $h$ (non-central chi squared) doesn’t actually depend on the value of $X.$

Comment: it's true, very nice observation.

Comment: if I take a subset of input that $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{A}^n = \{\pm \sqrt{\rho}\}^n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, hence the norm of input is preserved and inputs are still isotropically distributed but the cardinal of input set is finite. Can I say that the problem is still radial symmetry ? If it is the case, does it mean that given $H$, the distribution of $\mathbf{Y}$ does not change ?

$$P_{\mathbf{Y}|H,\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^n}(\mathbf{y}|h) = P_{\mathbf{Y}|H,\mathbf{X}\in\mathcal{A}^n}(\mathbf{y}|h)$$

Comment: @AlexTP: no, that isn’t radially symmetric, and convolving with a Gaussian won’t make it radially symmetric. I’m not sure it would be called an isotropic distribution, I don’t know if that is a general term. (Also I think that’s missing $n$ of $2n$ dimension)